# scroll down and up the div based on textbox value

Tags: javascript

I would like to hide the scroll bar on div tag but make it still scrollable. I have done this, but now I am wondering that how can a laptop users can scroll down and up the div contents if they don't have installed the mouse. Now I am thinking that how can I fix? code should be as  below:

```
<input type='text' id='value' value='certain percent' />
<input type='button' value='scroll up' onclick='scrollup()'  />
<input type='button' value='scroll up' onclick='scrolldown()'  />

function scrollup() {
    document.getElementById("my_div").scrollUp = document.getElementById('value').value;
}
function scrolldown() {
    document.getElementById("my_div").scrollDown = document.getElementById('value').value; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the scrollTop property as scrollUp and scrollDown do not exist.

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollTop)